# How do I change the way latex renders on firefox?

Tags: support, mathjax

I recently got a macbook and I have got mathjax on my browser. Now here is a screenshot of the latex that renders on math.se: [image]

How can I have a different font? For example I would like `\mathcal{O}(1)` to look like

[image]

instead of $$\mathcal{O}(1).$$

Comment: Please post a link to where you got this text...

Comment: Is this not how it's supposed to look?

Comment: @AlexBecker I have edited my question. In particular, see the last part of my question.

Comment: What's the difference exactly?

Comment: Have you changed *Mathjax Renderer* in [Mathjax PopUp Menu](http://www.mathjax.org/help/menu/)?

Comment: The question shown in the screenshot is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315273/how-should-i-think-about-very-ample-sheaves). BTW why do you mention ChatJax in connection with this, when it is not in chat?

Comment: @MartinSleziak Sorry, I meant to say mathjax.

Comment: I entirely fail to see the problem here. What is "rendering funny"? Are you complaining that the STIX font looks different from Computer/Latin Modern or the AMS fonts?

Comment: If you look in the Font Book application, does it list a number of STIX fonts in the All Fonts section? If so, what happens if you select all of them, choose Edit > Disable Fonts, and then restart your browser?

Comment: @WillieWong Perhaps my question was worded badly, but what I wanted to ask is how to change the font from what I currently have (I don't know the official latex name for the font) to the font for which `\mathcal{O}(1)` renders the way I want it to be.

Comment: @WillieWong I think if I ask the mathjax renderer to be "SVG" then everything works the way I want it to be. How can I put this as the default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you ask is about choosing a font for MathJAX. For that I'd recommend first looking at [this documentation page](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/HTML-CSS.html).

MathJAX by default uses local fonts when available, and web fonts next, and lastly image fonts. The currently only available web and image fonts are the `TeX` fonts, which happen to be the one you prefer.

Our current configuration on Math.SE seems to set `preferredFont` to `TeX`, but that only applies to local fonts.

The fact that you are seeing the `STIX` fonts used is because you do *not* have a local `TeX` font installed, and that you *do* have the `STIX` fonts installed.

If you do not want to use the `STIX` fonts, the simplest thing to do is to uninstall them. I am not familiar with Macs, so you are on your own there. (Presumably uninstalling a font when you know its name is not going to be *that* difficult.) This way MathJAX will fail to find any available local fonts and default to the web font (if your browser supports it) or image fonts (else), and in both cases the default for those are the `TeX` fonts which you seem to prefer.

Alternatively you can also try

- Installing the `TeX` fonts. This probably will require downloading the MathJax package and figuring out where the fonts lie in the archive and extracting them for installation.
- Write you own custom CSS overlay to overwrite the MathJAX configuration and replace `availableFonts: ["STIX","TeX"]` with `availableFonts: ["TeX"]` to prevent the use of `STIX` fonts on your computer.

Note that with the exception of actually installing a local copy of the `TeX` fonts, the other options will in effect cause web/image fonts to be used. Depending on how your computer handles caching and how fast your internet connection is this may make MathJAX appear noticeably slower.

Comment: Two additional comments. Safari includes STIX fonts since 5.1, that's why OSX and iOS users should expect to see it. The fonts are unsurprisingly in the fonts folder; otf is probably the easiest format. Here's a direct link: https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/tree/master/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf